# How to delete a line in docx with Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to delete a line in .docx file with apachi poi but I cannot.
I can change a line and make it "null" but the line is being empty, not deleted.
I have a code like below but it is only making a line empty.

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(templatesPath + templateName));
for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
    List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
    if(runs != null){
        for(int i = 0; i < runs.size(); i++){
            String line = p.getText();

            if(line != null && line.contains("@@THE_LINE_WILL_BE_DELETED@@")){
                runs.get(i).setText(null,0);
                // Here I need to delete the instead of setting as a null.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I you have an idea about how can I delete the lines which I want in docx? I searched a lot among other questions or forums but I cannot find?

Answer (score 0):

`XWPFDocument` has the method `removeBodyElement`, but since not every element needs to be a Paragraph, we can filter the body elements and then remove the specific paragraph like so:

```java
List<IBodyElement> elements = doc.getBodyElements();
for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
    var elem = elements.get(i);
    if(!elem.getElementType().equals(BodyElementType.PARAGRAPH)) continue;

    String line = ((XWPFParagraph) elem).getText();
    if (line != null && line.contains("@@THE_LINE_WILL_BE_DELETED@@")) {
        doc.removeBodyElement(i);
    }
}
```